# What difference does instantiating make?

Tags: java, instance

Suppose we have a class `World` and we've declared an instance `dreamWorld` of that class. How *Case 1* is different from *Case 2* other than it's one line shorter? What difference does instantiating in the second case actually make? I mean, afterall `dreamWorld` will be just the same in both cases, right?

**Case 1**:

```
void changeWorld(World outerWorld) {
    World dreamWorld;

    dreamWorld = outerWorld;
}
```

**Case 2**:

```
void changeWorld(World outerWorld) {
    World dreamWorld;

    dreamWorld = new World();
    dreamWorld = outerWorld;
}
```

where `outerWorld` is an object of `World` class created elsewhere and, say, provided as a method argument (I'm not sure if it matters how it is being provided).

**PS**
Thank you for all your prompt and helpful replies, guys, and sorry for my delayed gratitude (it took me time to read some literature that I felt would be necessary to fully understand your replies).

Comment: `dreamWorld = new World();` has absolutely no use in this example, since you're overwriting `dreamWorld ` on the next line.

Comment: Note: `dreamWorld` and `outerWorld` are *references* to a World object, not the object itself. Java only has primitive and reference variables.

Comment: The difference in the examples provided is that you are reassigning dreamWorld in the second case. The first line created a new instance of World and assigns it to dreamWorld. The second line immediately reassigns it to be a reference to outerWorld. The reference to the new instance created on the first line is then lost, and would be cleaned up during garbage collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the other answers are correct 1 and 2 the result will be logically the same, but Case 2 creates an instance of the object that gets lost and will be garbage collected.. (wasted logic)

Something that others are not taking into account is that your compiler will most likely identify this and remove the logic and the end byte code will be identical plus or minus a compile warning..

This said the fact that you are asking the question would suggest that you are not fully aware of what is happening when you use a = operator on references.

dreamworld and outerworld will be pointing to the same object instance.. you copied the references you did NOT make a copy of the object. so if you change outerworld the dreamworld will change with it.. You must use method or construct your own method that will make a clone/copy of the outerworld instance an assign it to the dreamworld instance.

REVISION: Depending on what the constructor for World class does the outcome could be DRASTICALLY different. for example it could update a static member of the class, create a file or any number of things. :) But if the class is a simple Bean, and the constructor has no side effects then all the answers here hold :).

Answer (score 6):

Case 2 is pointless. You instantiate a new `World` object and then lose the reference to it a line later when you assign `dreamWorld = outerWorld`, leaving it for the garbage collector to collect.

EDIT:
As @Rob pointed out, a caveat to the aforementioned statement is in the case that `World`'s constructor performs some external interaction, instantiating it will still take an affect. Assigning it to `dreamWorld`, however, is pointless, as this reference will be lost.

Comment: Not necessarily true.. If the constructor for the World class does some non trivial logic, like update a static member, sends a JMS message, creates a file, etc.... Just being a stickler.. I made the same original assumption too :)

Comment: @Rob good point, thanks - edited a new paragraph into my answer

Answer (score 1):

In Case 1 you:

- Declare a variable
- Set the variable to a value

In Case 2 you:

- Declare a variable
- Create a new object
- Set the variable to a value
- Set the variable to a value
- Destroy the recently created object

Both methods produce the same end result, but the second one also creates and destroys an object that was never used (which is, of course, entirely superfluous).

Answer (score 1):

In *Case 2*, one extra object will be created in `dreamWorld = new World();` line which will be garbage collected later because you are overwriting it

Answer (score 1):

The only difference it makes is that you've allocated some memory for another World object, which will then be mopped up by the garbage collector since you immediately nuke its reference.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously as stated in other answers your code is not setup properly. But 1 reason to instantiate would be if you were running this game on a server/multiplayer if person 1 got to level dreamWorld and person 2 started the game it would overwrite the World variable and person 1 would be magically on outerWorld.

Think of instantiation as creating an instance or object from a template.
You instantiate a class to create an object, a concrete instance of the class.

[How to instantiate an object in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986220/how-to-instantiate-an-object-in-java)